# Problem in lr_find() in Pytorch fastai course

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

While following the Jupyter notebooks for the course
I hit upon an error when these lines are run.
I know that the `cnn_learner` line has got no errors whatsoever, The problem lies in the `lr_find()` part
It seems that `learn.lr_find()` does not want to return two values! Although its documentation says that it returns a tuple. That is my problem.

These are the lines of code:

```
learn = cnn_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=error_rate)
lr_min,lr_steep = learn.lr_find()
```

The error says:

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

for the second line.
Also, I get this graph with one 'marker' which I suppose is either one of the values of `lr_min` or `lr_steep`
[This is the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZrbU.png)

When I run `learn.lr_find()` only, i.e. do not capture the output in `lr_min, lr_steep`;  it runs well but then I do not get the min and steep learning rates (which is really important for me)

I read through what `lr_find` does and it is clear that it returns a tuple. Its docstring says

> Launch a mock training to find a good learning rate and return suggestions based on `suggest_funcs` as a named **tuple**

I had duplicated the original notebook, and when I hit this error, I ran the original notebook, with the same results. I update the notebooks as well, but no change!
Wherever I have searched for this online, any sort of error hasn't popped up. The only relevant thing I found is that `lr_find()` returns different results of the learning rates after every run, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was having the same problem and I found that the `lr_find()` output's has updated. You can substitute the second line to `lrs = learn.lr_find(suggest_funcs=(minimum, steep, valley, slide))`, and then you just substitute where you using `lr_min` and `lr_steep` to `lrs.minimum` and `lrs.steep` respectively, this should work fine and solve your problem.

If you wanna read more about it, you can see [this post](https://forums.fast.ai/t/new-lr-finder-output/89236/3) that is in the fastai's forum.